Householder QR computation
I'm going over Householder reflections in relation to QR decomposition and I can't find how to exactly use Householder reflections to compute QR.
Considering the case in $\mathbb{R}^n$, given two non-zero vectors $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n,\;||x||=||y||$ we are looking for a unit vector $q$ such that $y=H(q)x=(I_n-qq^T)x$.
For $q_1=\frac{x-y}{||x-y||},\;q_2=\frac{x+y}{||x+y||}$ we get $y=H(q_2)x,\; y=-H(q_1)x.$
We can eliminate all but the first elements in vector $x$ by choosing $y=||x||e_1.$
Now if I want to use this to eliminate subdiagonal entries in a matrix, suppose we have done $k-1$ eliminations, do I choose $y=\frac{||x||}{\sqrt k}\sum_{i=1}^ke_i$ to eliminate the k. column?

Is the missing factor $2$ in $H(q)$ a typo or an error of yours?

Assume that you have already found a matrix $A'$ where all subdiagonal elements till the $(j-1)$-th column have been turned to zero. For subdiagonal elements of the form $(i,j)$ $i>j$ you take a sub-matrix (I assume you have a square matrix) where you have deleted the first $j-1$ rows and the first $j-1$ columns. You find an appropriate Householder matrix as you did before but this time for the submatrix. If you need a matrix for A' you add rows and columns in the opposite way you previously deleted to the new Householder (which is $(n-j+1)\times (n-j+1)$) that have 1 in the diagonal and zero elsewhere.
For vectors the procedure is similar. Delete (only rows), do the job then turn it to matrix for the original by adding 0-1 lines as mentioned.
